# What is the best api and tools for charts and graphs in Java EE web application?

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I use spring MVC application and Hibernate. I will show my data in charts, graphs and  export it in excel,pdf.I ask if I can use javascript api to fix this or what's the best way to show these charts and graphe.

And finally for reporting what's the best api to export to excel and pdf.
So what's the best api or library to use thanks.

Please help.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: yes to recommend best api or library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). Open source and easy to use. I have added helping code on my blog at [this link](https://sohaibnasser.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/jasper-reports-in-word-excel-pdf-html/). Exporters for word, pdf, excel and html are mentioned there.